# Bathroom fan light combo power source is in ceiling..from 12/2 to 12/3 to gfci to a double pole switch

Tags: wiring, bathroom, gfci, exhaust

Remodeling bathroom...removed light installing exhaust fan light combo...power source is already in Ceiling which is 12/2..from the 12/2 it will turn into 12/3  to go down to a gfci outlet and from the gfci to a double pole switch to control light separately from exhaust fan

Comment: check your spelling

Comment: Is that 12/2 dedicated to the bathroom in question or does it feed other things as well?

Comment: Do you have a question? All I see...is...a run on...statement. Please take the [tour] to get an idea of how this site works, then [edit] your question to actually ask a question that we can try to answer for you.